# Typesafety in javascript or how to avoid pretty hard to detect type related errors

Tags: javascript

I come from the Java world, i.e. a typesafe world and am right now doing a couple of things for which I need client side execution using javascript.

I keep running into pretty hard to detect errors at times due to the non typification of JS and am wondering if there is any way to prevent it beforehand. E.g. setting sth like "use typification;" or via some tool that does these checks before executing like a compiler does.

E.g. last time was when I was creating a face in three.js. There depening on order of vertices a face is front-facing or not. I had mixed that up and then copy pasted parameters in which case I also copied a bracket too much so it ended up in the wrong place with just calling the method with one instead of three vertices which of course resulted in an error. However in line 2107 of three.js code and it took a while to figure out this little copy paste issue. Comparing to java the compiler would have directly complained that i try calling the method with 1 instead of 3 parameters...

Hope there is sth like it. Or do have some tips how to spot such things faster?

Cheers
Tom

Comment: This will go a fair amount for you considering your troubles. https://www.typescriptlang.org/ - It almost forces you to write your code in a more defined manner, setting types as well as shouting at you if you're accessing a non-existant member in your current scope. Together with a good text editor, such as VSCode or Atom etc. you can get intellisense working much like with a language like Java. It has a type definition file for Three.js too, which is a bonus in your case - definitely recommend it personally.

Comment: Code is always better than words. You may need to add some code into your question for clarifying your issue.

Comment: `"the compiler would have directly complained that i try calling the method with 1 instead of 3 parameters"` - I would think the difference between `someMethod(aParameter)` and `someMethod(aParameter, anotherParameter, aThirdParameter)` would be contextually evident.  If the `someMethod` operation would require more than 1 input, and only 1 is provided, that should jump out as a problem.  I *suspect* that part of the problem here is that the code you're writing isn't clear in the first place and you're relying on the compiler to tell you what the code itself should be telling you.

Comment: @Tresdin I believe OPs problem is more conceptual, as they like to rely on a strict environment, whereas Javascript dies quietly in the corner about some issues. Not an immediate problem with their current codebase.

Comment: @N.J.Dawson It's still better to have code included as examples because it'll be easier for us to provide some tips, workarounds or recommendations for the specific case.

Comment: @David Great point. Trying to use javascript without a clear understanding of how the language works and expecting it / forcing it to act like java, or any other language for that matter, is typically a BAD idea. Javascript has all sorts of ways to do type checking using typeOf , === , etc. as well as numerous tools (e.g. typescript) for writing in a more "type safe" environment. Use what is available to you, but also please, please spend time learning the semantics/grammar/syntax of the language.

Answer (score 1):

There are various linting tools which you can use to scan your javascript files before you actually use them. The popular ones in the industry are JSLint, JSHint, JSCS and ESLint.

They come inbuilt with various rule sets which you can configure and you can also add your own rules.

You can compare these to checkstyles and PMD from the JAVA world.

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of answers. But first, need to clarify: Java is not type-safe (see: `NullPointerException`, history of).

But to get closer to type-safety in any dynamic language you have the option to pepper your code with asserts. This can to some degree be automated, it *may* cause performance issues. This is the route I [usually take](https://github.com/jasmith79/js-typed), but I certainly wouldn't do it with three.js.

For JavaScript specifically, you have two additional options: [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) and [Flow](https://flowtype.org/).

TypeScript is a dialect of JavaScript with type annotations that gets compiled down to plain JS. Flow is a static analyzer written in OCaml that tries to infer types in your JS code and check them.